# 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2-4: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, sublimetext3

```
# coding: utf-8

station = open("stations.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8")

for line in station:
    name = line.strip().split(" - ")
    print(name)

station.close()
```

If I build this, it shows an error message like below

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File 
>   "/path/\u1105\u1175\u1109\u1173\u1110\u1173\u1103\u1171\u110c\u1175\u11b8\u1100\u1175(\u110c\u1162\u1100\u1171\u110c\u1165\u11a8).py",
>   line 7, in 
>       print(name)
>
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
>   2-4: ordinal not in range(128)
>
> [Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
>
> [cmd:
>   ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5',
>   '-u', '/path/name.py']]
>
> [dir: /path/]
>
> [path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]

For three days, I couldn't do anything. Help me please

Comment: Hmmm...what happens if you replace the loop with `print(station.read())`?

Comment: @Alex Hall Same result :(

Comment: Take a look at this: http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2014/01/12/python-unicode-console-output.html